# Editing lists in a dictionary Python 3.7

Tags: python

I am trying to print out a dictionary that shows a students ID, Name and Grades so it looks like this "ID:{'Name': 'Students Name', Grades[Grade1, Grade2, Grade3....]. When I am doing this and print out the dictionary it will only print our the grade for the last assignment for each student dictionary. For example if student 1 got a 30 on the last assignment and student 2 got a 40 on the last assignment. The output is:

```
enter code here
1:{'Name': 'Student 1', 'Grades': [30, 40]}
2:{'Name': 'Student 2', 'Grades': [30, 40]}
```

My original problem was everyscore for every student was in the dictionary, I thought I fixed this by emptying the Grades list in the loop after the grades go in. But now i have this problem. Im not quite sure what the problem is and Im going to try and work on it but any help would be appreciated. MY code is below.

```
enter code here
students = {}
grades = []
while True:
    blank = {} 

    student_name = input("What is the student's name?  ")
    student_id = input("What is the student's ID number?  ")
    blank['Name'] = student_name
    blank['Grades'] = grades
    students[student_id] = blank
    y_or_n = input("Would you like to enter another student? Yes or No  ")
    if y_or_n == "Yes":
        continue
    else:
        break

   homework_assignments = int(input("How many homework assignments were 
given?  "))
for i in students.keys():
    print("Please enter the grades for {}".format(students[i]['Name']))
    for j in range (1, homework_assignments + 1):
        grade =  int(input("What was the grade for homework {}?".format(j)))
    grades.append(grade)        
    for i in students.keys():
        students[i]['Grades'] = grades
        grade = []
for key in students.keys():
    print("{}:{}".format(key, students[key]))
```

Comment: You are modifying the size of your dictionary with `students['Grades'] = grades`. In the first iteration, you will be creating a key called 'Grades', hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you call`students['Grades'] = grades` you are modifying the same dictionary while iterating through it's keys. The correct code should be `students[i]['Grades'] = grades` since you have declared the Grades as a nested structure of students above. There is another mistake, you are using the varibale `i` as an index to iterate through the assignments as well as the students, which results in `i` being incremented in an unexpected manner. Try the following snippet.

```
for i in students.keys():
    print("Please enter the grades for {}".format(students[i]['Name']))
    for j in range (1, homework_assignments + 1):
        grade =  int(input("What was the grade for homework {}? ".format(i)))
        if grade < 0 or grade > 100:
            print("Grades need to be between 0 - 100")
        grades.append(grade)

    students[i]['Grades'] = grades
```

Comment: I tried that and it did fix the error that came up, but now in the dictionary, when I print it out it is printing out all of the grades for all of the students instead of printing out the specific grades for the students. So now I have to figure out how to store the grades separately  in the dictionary. Thank very much for the help!

Comment: @sjn40618 Think about the way you are storing grades. You are storing them in a list, which can be accessed by the `Grade` key of each student dict.

Answer (score 0):

Some things I have noticed:

Your checking of invalid grades does nothing, the grade will still be added incorrectly. To fix this, you need to make sure that the grade is not added if it is outside that range, and that you **repeat** that i'th iteration.

This is not really accomplish-able with a for loop in your current structure, maybe a while loop would suit it better.

I also noticed you have used the variable i for two of your loops, which means that it is getting overwritten and causing confusing things to happen.

There are a whole host of logical errors towards the bottom and I think it would help you if you printed out the `students` dictionary before you print it to see its structure.

From my perspective I see has keys that are the student's ID numbers, with corresponding values of their name and this grades list. It also has a key that is `'Grades'` which holds the same grades list.

The reason you are seeing all of the grades is because of a small detail about how python handles lists. The problem you are seeing is related to [assignment and copying](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html) - you want to copy the contents at that point and then empty it after you are done assigning so the next student has an empty list. What you are currently doing is *assigning* the list which is effectively making every grade list point to the same list.

I'd personally like to stray away from literally writing the code for you, but if you have further questions just comment them and I will guide you through it.